# Different performance in different Linux distributions

Tags: linux, system-performance

On my machine I have both Debian and Ubuntu installed. Because I'm going to move everything to Debian, I just installed Mathematica there.
My concern is about the different results of `BenchmarkReport`, which gives me 0.93 in Debian and 1.05 in Ubuntu. I was wondering how this can be possible.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: What kind of numbers do you get when running the benchmark several times in a row, in the same OS?